# NodeJS and Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

If I have some HTML code:

```
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="User Name" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="button"><a href="/api/users/">Login</a></button>
    </div>
```

and when I click on the login button, it goes to the /api/users/ function in my nodejs file. How do I pass the strings stored in the username and password in the HTML code? Using sqlite3.

```
app.get('/api/users/', function (req, res) {
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users;';
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
       var result = {};
       result["users"] = [];
       if (err) {
            result["error"] = err.message;
       }else {
            rows.forEach((row) => {
               result["users"].push(row);
           });
       }
       res.json(result);
    });
});
```

I want to execute some type of function, where if the username and password does not exist, than add it to the table "users" and redirect to another HTML file.

Comment: use a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) on the frontend, and [`Request.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) and [`Response.redirect`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a html form. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). You're HTML is just sending an empty get request to your API, a form will send the data as well.

Comment: I have changed it to a form, but how do I access these values in the back end